# Date time format for query parameter in rest url

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, postman

I am using joda DateTime as parameter.

Use Custom Date Time format for request query parameter in spring REST

I have tried with @DateTimeFormat annotation.

I have tried with custom converter.

```
   @GetMapping("/users/time")
   public ResponseEntity<User> findByTimeRange(final DateTime from, final DateTime to) {
   }
```

Spring REST only support `"2019-09-01T7:32:56.235-05:30"` but i want to use `"2019-09-01T7:32:56"`

Comment: Which `DateTime` type is that? The one from Joda-Time?

Comment: yes its joda-time

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you would need a custom formatter and pass parameters as Strings and parse them with it. Here is the working code using Joda Time and tested with your input:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = 
                     DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

@GetMapping("/users/time")
public ResponseEntity<User> findByTimeRange(@RequestParam("from") String fromParam,
                                            @RequestParam("to") String toParam) {
    DateTime from = FORMATTER.parseDateTime(fromParam);
    DateTime to = FORMATTER.parseDateTime(toParam);

    // Do your search part...
}
```